# React signup page syntax error at return of render function

Tags: reactjs, express

i have a react sign up page that returns an error at the return of the render method. It shows a syntax error whenever i run the code on the browser. The code is meant to pass data to a server endpoint.I have looked all over and can't find the cause of the error. I would like to know the probable cause of this problem and the line of action or code to correct this error

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            name:'',
            town: '',
            long: '',
            lat: ''
         }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const Register = {
            name: this.state.name,
            town: this.state.town,
            long: this.state.long,
            lat: this.state.lat
        }
    }

}
    fetch ('https://localhost3000/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'name',
            city: 'city',
            long: 'long',
            lat: 'lat'
        })
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(Register){
        console.log(Register)
    });

    *render() {  
        return ( *
            <div>
                <form className="form-style">
                    <label>
                    Name:<br/>
                    <input name='name' value={this.state.name}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Name"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <label>
                    Town:<br/>
                    <input name='town' value={this.state.town}
                    placeholder="Enter town where farm is located"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <label>
                    Longitude:<br/>
                    <input name='long' value={this.state.long}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Longitude"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/><br/>
                    Latitude:<br/>
                    <input name='lat' value={this.state.lat}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Latitude"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <Link><a href="https://www.latlong.net/" target="_blank">
                    Get Longitude and Latitude of current location here</a></Link><br/>
                    <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                    disabled={!this.state.name}
                    disabled={!this.state.long}
                    disabled={!this.state.lat}
                    disabled={!this.state.town}>
                    Register</button>
                </form>


            </div>    
        )

    };


export default Register ;`
```

Comment: Please share with us what the error says

Comment: ./components/registeruser.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\OK\Desktop\Kemz's\Projects\Weather\components\registeruser.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (53:13)

Comment: Why is there an `*` in front of the render method?

Comment: @ChukwukaOnwana There are multiple online syntax checker tools available. You need not to take this question to stackoverflow. In your case, you can paste the code here https://babeljs.io/repl/ and check for syntax yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced `}` in your code right after you define the `onSubmit` function. This closed off your component and made the rest of your code invalid. You're also trying to call fetch inside your component without it being inside any lifecycle-method, function or event. This will lead to a syntax error.
Try this instead :)

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            name:'',
            town: '',
            long: '',
            lat: ''
         }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch ('https://localhost3000/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'name',
            city: 'city',
            long: 'long',
            lat: 'lat'
        })
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(Register){
        console.log(Register)
    })
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const Register = {
            name: this.state.name,
            town: this.state.town,
            long: this.state.long,
            lat: this.state.lat
        }
    }

    render(){  
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="form-style">
                    <label>
                    Name:<br/>
                    <input name='name' value={this.state.name}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Name"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <label>
                    Town:<br/>
                    <input name='town' value={this.state.town}
                    placeholder="Enter town where farm is located"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <label>
                    Longitude:<br/>
                    <input name='long' value={this.state.long}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Longitude"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/><br/>
                    Latitude:<br/>
                    <input name='lat' value={this.state.lat}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Farm Latitude"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                    </label><br/>
                    <Link><a href="https://www.latlong.net/" target="_blank">
                    Get Longitude and Latitude of current location here</a></Link><br/>
                    <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                    disabled={!this.state.name}
                    disabled={!this.state.long}
                    disabled={!this.state.lat}
                    disabled={!this.state.town}>
                    Register</button>
                </form>

            </div>    
        )
    }

  }

export default Register
```

Comment: it now returns a different error:- Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Comment: @ChukwukaOnwana have you set up a Router for your application using react-router-dom?